# Epson Artisan 835 printer won't configure in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, printing, configuration, epson

I've used an Epson Artisan 835 printer for a number of years, using several different releases of Ubuntu.  It was always recognized and set up with no special interaction.  It doesn't seem to be supported in Ubuntu 20.04.  I've tried both upgrading from 19.10 and using a clean install of 20.04 and I can't get this printer to be recognized.  I've tried installing it both as network attached and USB attached with the same outcome.  The furthest I've gotten is a printer set up, to which I can send documents, but then I get a "Printer Stopped" message and the job goes nowhere.

I have set up 20.04 with an Epson Work-Force printer and that configured as expected.

Has anyone had this issue and come up with a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the proper approach to get this going.  It appears that this printer has fallen off the list of printers whose support is loaded by default.

1. Go to Epson's web site, find the driver, and download it, saving it as a file. For my system, it is: epson-inkjet-printer-artisan-725-835-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
2. Verify that dpkg is loaded. it's no longer loaded by default in 20.04.  You can load it with "sudo apt-get install dpkg".
3. Load the driver using dpkg:
   sudo dpkg -i /home/dean/Downloads/epson-inkjet-printer-artisan-725-835-series_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb
4. Now, you can set up your printer using the gui printer configuration within settings. I specified the URI using the dnssd protocol.

Print a test page to verify a functional printer.